# Correct frequency axis using FFT

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

How can I get the correct frequency vector to plot using the **FFT** of `MATLAB`?

My problem:

```
N      = 64;
n      = 0:N-1; 
phi1   = 2*(rand-0.5)*pi; 
omega1 = pi/6;
phi2   = 2*(rand-0.5)*pi; 
omega2 = 5*pi/6;
w      = randn(1,N); % noise
x      = 2*exp(1i*(n*omega1+phi1))+4*sin(n*omega2+phi2);
h      = rectwin(N).';
x      = x.*h;
X      = abs(fft(x));
```

Normally I'd do this :

```
 f = f     = Fs/Nsamples*(0:Nsamples/2-1); % Prepare freq data for plot
```

The problem is this time I do not have a Fs (sample frequency).

How can I do it correctly in this case?

Comment: Do you have the length (in seconds or whatever) of the recorded time signal? From the difference of the time points you could estimate fs.

Comment: The length in this case is 64 samples. What can I do?

Comment: My question was targeting the length of you signal in sense of a time measure (seconds or minutes etc).

Comment: @Irreducible unfortunately the signal is not really, I've create in MATLAB, `x`. I do not have the duration of it. Thank anyways, it's already working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a *Fs*, simply set it to 1 (as in one sample per sample). This is the typical solution I've always used and seen everybody else use. Your frequencies will run from 0 to 1 (or -0.5 to 0.5), without units. This will be recognized by everyone as meaning "periods per sample".

**Edit**

From your comment I conclude that you are interested in radial frequencies. In that case you want to set your plot x-axis to

```
omega = 2*pi*f;
```

Comment: I my case I think there're 3 frequencies, one from the complex exp and two from the sine function. How can I make the frequency axis match those?

Comment: @Dirac If you're interested in matching your `omega1` and `omega2`, use radial frequencies. See my edited answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. It's working now.

Comment: @Cris Luengo I posted a quite similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399956/how-to-plot-2d-power-spectrum), but it's a 2D image. In that case, would sampling rate of 1 still valid? But many journals used ranges that's hundreds larger (like the one in the PDF file I attached), what actually define my sampling rate in an image?

Comment: @GregorIsack basically the frequency axis is done like this, `f = (-nfft/2:nfft/2-1)*Fs/(nfft)`, where `nfft` is the number of points to do the `FFT`and `Fs` is the frequency sample. If you want only the positive side, `f = (0: nfft-1)*Fs/nfft`.